# Using GlobalProtect VPN and remote desktop to a work computer from a personal one - am I vulnerable to spying?

Tags: remote-desktop

Good evening,

I'm far from a computer expert, just a user. I have an old (10 years) laptop provided by my employer to work remotely, but my personal laptop is only a couple years old and has upgraded RAM. I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to install the required VPN and use remote desktop to access my work drives from my personal computer instead of using both? Could this open me up to the company spying on my personal activities, files, etc.? I know almost anything is possible, but I don't work for an IT company or anything, so whether they have the expertise to do something really advanced is doubtful. I'm just wondering whether this is a best practice or not.

Thanks for any input.

AF

Comment: First make sure that you are even allowed to use a device not provided and not managed by the company to do this. Commonly this is not allowed since one does not sufficiently trust the security of a private device.  Only if you are allowed to run the software on your private device the question is even relevant, since otherwise you might be in legal trouble by violating the employers security policy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my company access my computer via the VPN?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31086/can-my-company-access-my-computer-via-the-vpn), [Can a company using GlobalProtect see the websites I'm visiting?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144243/can-a-company-using-globalprotect-see-the-websites-im-visiting), [Can the GlobalProtect VPN of my company track websites when Disabled?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224965/can-the-globalprotect-vpn-of-my-company-track-websites-when-disabled).

Comment: Thank-you. I am permitted to use personal devices. In fact, it’s rare for employees to have a work-owned device, and the reason the whole system was set up in the first place was to allow remote work on private computers. And thank you for the links, they answered my question.